# iOS simulator - trick to using TV Out?

Tags: ios, video, simulator, out, television

I'm using the iOS simulator from xcode 4.3.1,
and the "TV Out" option doesn't seem to be doing its thing.
I've tried it with a variety of simulated devices and tv resolutions,
but always just get a black screen.
Perhaps it doesn't support the default Mirroring which comes w/ the iPad 2 & 3 ?
That is, when i hook up a VGA cable to an actual iPad 2, i get a nice mirroring of the 'desktop' and whatever app i run.

Possibly the simulator only respects explicit video-out to screen 1 ?
eg:

```
UIScreen*    secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
```

tia,
Orion

Answer (score 0):

I found [this forum post](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/69546-tv-out-on-simulator-doesnt-really-work.html) which pointed out that there's a problem with landscape showing up on the secondary screen for the simulator.

Every time I've tested outputting to a secondary screen seems to work in portrait, but not in landscape. Hope that helps!